# Symfony4: Security user session saving from DB (Entity) does not work

Tags: php, symfony

When I was verifying the operation with Symfony4, when I entered the ID and password, the same login page was displayed.
It seems that I haven't passed the information necessary for making it behaviorally serious, but I don't know how to fix it.
Putting `$this->salt` in `selialize()` didn't change.
Are there any other problems?
It worked in Symfony 3.4.

https://symfony.com/doc/4.0/security/entity_provider.html

Staff.php

```php
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\AdvancedUserInterface;
use Ahi\Sp\CommonBundle\Model\Lib\Parameters;

/**
 * staffentity
 *
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Ahi\Sp\CommonBundle\Model\Repository\StaffRepository")
 * @ORM\Table(name="staff", uniqueConstraints={
 *      @ORM\UniqueConstraint(name="idx_staff_unique", columns={"staff_login_id"}),
 *      @ORM\UniqueConstraint(name="idx_image_mail_unique", columns={"image_mail"})
 * })
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
 */
class Staff implements AdvancedUserInterface, \Serializable
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", options={"comment"="Staff ID"})
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;
   /**
     * password
     * @ORM\Column(name="password", type="string", length=255, nullable=true, options={"comment"="password"})
     */
    protected $password;
    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }
    /**
     * Set raw password.
     *
     * @param string $rawPassword
     */
    public function setRawPassword($rawPassword)
    {
        $this->rawPassword = $rawPassword;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get raw password.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getRawPassword()
    {
        return $this->rawPassword;
    }

    /**
     * Hash password generation
     * @ORM\PrePersist
     * @ORM\PreUpdate
     */
    public function makeHashPassword()
    {
        if ($this->rawPassword) {
            $encoderFactory = Parameters::getEncoderFactory();
            $this->password = $encoderFactory->getEncoder($this)->encodePassword(
            $this->rawPassword, Parameters::getParameter('staff_password_salt')
            );
        }
    }
    /**
     * Check if the password is correct
     * @param string $password password
     * @return boolean True if the password is correct
     */
    public function confirmPassword($rawPassword)
    {
        $encoderFactory = Parameters::getEncoderFactory();
        $password = $encoderFactory->getEncoder($this)->encodePassword(
        $rawPassword, Parameters::getParameter('staff_password_salt')
       );
        return ($password === $this->password);
    }
    public function getSalt()
    {
        return Parameters::getParameter('staff_password_salt');      
    }

    public function serialize()
    {
        return serialize(array(
            $this->id,
            $this->password,
        ));
    }

    public function unserialize($serialized)
    {
        list (
            $this->id,
            $this->password,
        ) = unserialize($serialized);
    }
```

Comment: Whenever you mess around with the user serialize interface you typically have to implement the User\EquatableInterface.  It basically tries to determine if the serialized user information is still the same as the information in the database.  You might start by not implementing \Serializible and see if that helps.  Be sure to remove your sessions if you do.  If not then search around for info and examples on EquatableInterface.

Comment: @Cerad Thank you. Thanks to you, I was able to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As advised by @Cerad, I implemented EquatableInterface and it works.

https://symfony.com/doc/4.0/security/custom_provider.html

```php
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\EquatableInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;

class Staff implements AdvancedUserInterface, \Serializable, EquatableInterface
{

   /**
     * @see \Serializable::serialize()
     */
    public function serialize()
    {
        return serialize(array(
            $this->id,
            $this->password,
      ));
    }

    /**
     * @see \Serializable::unserialize()
     */
    public function unserialize($serialized)
    {
        list (
            $this->id,
            $this->password,
      ) = unserialize($serialized, array('allowed_classes' => false));
    }

    public function isEqualTo(UserInterface $user)
    {
        if (!$user instanceof Staff) {
            return false;
        }

        if ($this->password !== $user->getPassword()) {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
```